# Intersect raster or laz (pointcloud) with vector polygons

Tags: qgis, point-cloud

I am a vector trained GIS person and wish to add the value of a pointcloud to my vector data. A friend of mine suggested cloudcompare but said it was also possible using my beloved QGIS. I work with postgres in combination with qgis often.

Because of my vector way of thinking i am looking for tools to intersect or add a column to the points with the vector polygon id.

I have the feeling that i am not thinking in the right direction. I am doing this in my free time and it will take a while for me to figure this one out. So i am asking for tips and advise to extract the data of a pointcloud in vector polygons.

Comment: Which value/data of point cloud would you like to add to the vector data? What does the vector data look like? What if you have more than one point/return intersecting/overlapping the geometry? Add some screenshots to illustrate what you have, and what you want. Tks.